# Calculus Made Easy, Chapter 21, Exercise 14

Tags: calculus, integration

This chapter in Thompson's book includes 'Dodges, Pitfalls and Triumphs' in using integration techniques -mainly integration by parts and substitution. I have been doing de exercises (boy, is integration tough...) and am currently stuck with number 14:

$\displaystyle\int\frac{x}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2x^2}} dx$

Any clue on how to start tackling this beast, people? I've tried integration by parts, splitting into partial fractions and rationalizing the denominator. In theory, it can't use more fancy techniques...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Substitution works, notice that $$u(x)=a^2-b^2x^2$$ $$\frac{du}{dx}=-2b^2x$$
I will let you continue from here.

You can check the answer is

> $$\int \frac{x}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2x^2}}\, {\rm d}x=-\frac{\sqrt{a^2-b^2x^2}}{b^2}+C,\quad b\not=0 $$

Comment: (+1) how do you do that spoiler thing?

Comment: @DS I think it's >!

Comment: thanks @SineoftheTime

Comment: @SineoftheTime and congratulations for hitting the 2k mark

Comment: @DS thank you for noticing that

Comment: Thanks! I actually *had* tried u substitution as well, but after I got the 1/u^(1/2) integral, I just couldn't think of how easy this is to solve -like I tried multiplying top and bottom by square root of u and tried to integrate that by parts and/or split into into partial fractions. I feel extremely dumb...

Comment: @DS you can find out how anything is done in a question or answer by hitting "Edit" which will show you the source code.  (That's if you have enough reputation for edit privileges - not sure how much you need.)

Answer (score 3):

Substitution at the start works best here. Integrating by parts would work too, but you'll ultimately have to enforce a substitution somewhere.

$$\int\frac{x}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2x^2}}\,dx = uv - \int v\,du$$

where $u=x$ and $dv=\dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2x^2}}$. To evaluate $v$, try substituting one of

- $x = -\dfrac{2at}{b^2+t^2}$ ([Euler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution))
- $x=\dfrac ab\sin(t)$ ([trigonometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution))
- $x=\dfrac ab\tanh(t)$ (hyperbolic)